# How do you call the space inside train?

Tags: expressions

[image: How do you call the space inside trains?]

I wonder how do you call the space inside trains like above.
I found some words: stock, carriage, cabin, compartment, etc through dictionaries, however, I don't know the differences among the words.

Would you tell me the differences among "carriage", "cabin", "compartment" and let me know how can I say in case of the picture attached above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Carriage" is the entire train car, not just the interior, so that's not the right word.

"Compartment" and "cabin" would both work. The difference between the two words is that a cabin is meant for people, while a compartment could be for people, or for other things like baggage.

But most people would just say "the inside of the train".

Comment: Thank you. Then, A sentence like "All of the passengers, please wait for a while inside of this train." would be okay?

Comment: @LucianoJeong Idiomatically, such an announcement would be something like this: *Attention passengers. [Something has happened.] Please wait **onboard** the train. [Thank you for your patience.]* The use of the more general *onboard* is more common than any specific descriptive term about the interior space of the train.

Comment: Or "Please remain on the train"

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you

Comment: "Please remain on the train" is more direct, so that's what I'd use.

Comment: And if you want to encourage them to remain on the train, follow that with something like "the bar in the dining car is now open". Assuming your train is so equipped.